# Search All Drives using File Extension in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, filesystems

In VB.NET, how can I search all hard-drives (regardless of whatever a machine has C, D or more) for specific file types (for example .mp3)? I want the file path to be return along with the file size.

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

This link demonstrates how to get all the logical drives

http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=4708

Then from inside the for each you need to call a recursive directory search such as

http://bigbadcode.com/2005/09/12/recursive-file-and-folder-listing-vbnet/

Between these two pages you should be able to build what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use classes from System.IO namespaces - `FileInfo`, `DirectoryInfo`, `DriveInfo` and `Path`.

```
Dim drive=System.IO.Path.GetPathRoot(FileName)
```